# style not applying for jquery appended elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to append some elements when clicking an button. Appending is working fine and css style is not applying for that appended elements. Here is my HTML

```
$(".tab-pane").on('click',"#addicon_itenary", function () {
    $("#multicity_div").append(
        '<div class="row" style="padding-left:15px">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group label-floating float-label-control" id="select-field">
                    <div class="float-label-control">
                        <label class="control-label">From<small>(required)</small></label>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control dropdown" id="country-list">
                        <option>Australia</option>
                        <option>China</option>
                        <option>India</option>
                        <option>Pakistan</option>
                        <option>Russia</option>
                        <option>United Arab Emirates</option>
                        <option>United Kingdom</option>
                        <option>United States of America</option>
                        <option>Zimbabwe</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="tocity">
                <div class="form-group label-floating float-label-control" id="select-field">
                    <div class="float-label-control">
                        <label class="control-label">To<small>(required)</small></label>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="country-list-to">
                        <option>Australia</option>
                        <option>China</option>
                        <option>India</option>
                        <option>Pakistan</option>
                        <option>Russia</option>
                        <option>United Arab Emirates</option>
                        <option>United Kingdom</option>
                        <option>United States of America</option>
                        <option>Zimbabwe</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                    <label class="control-label">Depart<small>(required)</small></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker">
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <i class="material-icons"id="deleteicon_itenary">delete</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <i class="material-icons"id="addicon_itenary">add</i> 
            </div>
        </div>'
    );
});
```

How to apply style for this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can i see a fiddle for this case .

Comment: Where is the CSS styles which aren't applying?

Comment: You have a `float-label-
control` instead of `float-label-control` ?!

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError That is bootstrap styles.. They are stored in another field.. You can see the bootstrap class names in the code.

Comment: @A.Wolff That is not the problem here... None of the style is aplying

Comment: try giving a class to the appended parent div with  your desired styles beforehand.?? i would also be helpful if u make a jsfiddle for this

Comment: there is a space between `float-label-` and `control`. If you are trying to assign `class="float-label-control"` try with no space and check

Comment: I want to see the styles not the classes - I can't troubleshoot arbitrary classes. Set up a Code Snippet with all relevant code and include the bootstrap css library, I need an MVCE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AbSin There is no space between float-label and control.. While pasting the code here it pasted like this :)

Comment: Can anybody give me a sample code please

Comment: `Can anybody give me a sample code please` A sample code of what? You have to provide sample code replicating issue, not the other way...

Comment: @Shanmugapriya the best way to get answer here is create a jsfiddle and share. Then its easier for us to also understand. PS: You can search for existing jsfiddles with bootstrap and jquery loaded to ease your effort.

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context... Is it your issue? Maybe, maybe not... What's wrong with providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's not working on your side, I tried removing all of the divs and retained 2 divs just to check if its really not working,

here is the link, https://jsfiddle.net/rsr757zv/

as you can see, the inline styling takes effect,

HTML File - I created a simple html file just to make it all work, since you didn't provide your html file, I dont know what your html file looks like, So this may be a little far different from what you expect but my goal here is to append an html file together with its styling,

```
 <div class='tab-pane'>
      Some TAB-PANE
      <br>
      <button id='addicon_itenary' type='button'>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div id='multicity_div'>
      append here
    </div>
```

script file

```
<script>
 $(".tab-pane").on('click',"#addicon_itenary",function () {
 $("#multicity_div").append("<div class='row' style='padding-left:15px;border:1px solid #333;'><div class='col-xs-12' style='background:#0f0;'>aa</div></div>");
});
</scipt>
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answer.. This is my problem.. Inline style is working and bootstrap style is not working

Comment: i have updated the jsfiddle, the bootstrap styling takes effect on my button,

Comment: You given inline styles.. I don't want to give inline styles.. All my styles are already written in another file.. Just i want to call the class names

Comment: i edited the fiddle,  im using bootstrap button classes, and it is working, the problem might be the way you are including your bootstrap files, can you edit your question and add your main html file with included bootstrap files,